# BlackOps Zombie Strategy

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, cod-black-ops-zombies

What's your favorites strategies for the map **Kino der Toten** in the Zombie mod of Black Ops ?

Comment: Hi MathieuF! The "best" strategy is something of a subjective thing, and is hard to give a good answer for. Could you be a little more specific in your question?

Comment: Hi mate, I have edited my question !

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not specific enough. What do you need help with? For example, if you have trouble finding a counter for a popular strategy on this map, you may want to explain what it is and ask for a counter :)

Comment: I'm not trying to get help. I'm just looking to have a discussion on strategies. I would like to know the views of several players. :)

Comment: This is not a real question. You could discuss strategies at length in the Black Ops Steam Group: forums.steampowered.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=779

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. Quite interested to hear too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience; it is faster to reach higher levels with less people.

It is easier to survive using the path on the upper area from the lobby 'til you reach the stage and turn-on the power.

For the 1st and 2nd wave of hell hounds; you must already reached the room with MP40 and quickly kill the dogs on sight or just group together in a corner.

Reach the stage as quick as possible and before turning on the power make sure you have the claymore and atleast 2,500 for the Joggernog.

If you already found the mystery/random weapon box aim immediately for the Thundergun, Raygun, and Monkey Bomb; this is applicable for solo. Other players should aim for the Raygun, Monkey Bomb, and other assault rifle, SMG, or LMG but I prefer the packed-a-punched M14.

**This is where the real strategy will go:**
Don't use the claymores immediately, just place them on the stage, facing the wall, where you can pick them easily on times of emergency.

The ThunderGun carrier should be good at dodging zombies 'coz he will just kite zombies on the stage, run around the stage in a circular form, make the ThunderGun as your primary weapone, when it seems there are enough/too much zombies following you or in emergency; fire it.

The other players(if there are) might stay next to the M14(make sure that the door near it is closed and the ThunderGun carrier would run in smaller circle that near the dressing room) or run around from lobby, upstairs, to the dressing room, and back to the stage and use the teleporter if available. Just don't be in the way of the ThunderGunner. The other players should stick together.

If someone is down, one should use the Monkey Bomb and quickly revive the downed player.

And the most important of all is communication for newbies or proper coordination if you know the map very well and don't have a headset.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Wait in the first room (Lobby) until round 4.
2. Make a crawler zombie or just keep one zombie and make sure people have good amounts of points, then open the door to the MP40 room from the stairs in the lobby by the M14.
3. Open the next door, but if the mystery box is in the first room, do the box and make sure that someone has near enough or enough to open the door and stay there a few rounds.
4. When the Hell Dogs come in, everyone should get in the corner by the Speed Cola machine and make sure to reload before getting the max ammo.
5. After holding this position becomes difficult, go to the stage. DON'T turn on the power. Get two people to guard the windows and the other two to guard the door to the dressing room; the person by the door at a window can help.
6. After holding this position gets hard, turn on the power and turn on the mainframe of the teleporter. Run through to the lobby, turn on the switch, run back to the teleporter and wait.
7. The rest is pretty much running in circles with thunder guns on the stage and building points to the Pack-A-Punched crossbow, to buy perks, to get the random box, or to other things you desire.

Answer (score 0):

knife for the first three rounds create a crawler and open as much rooms as possible buy the ak 74 u hunt dogs then train for a few rounds until I can open all dors.  I also hit all three rocks in later rounds to motivate me and my best round is 147 on i pad and 107 on x box